# Locate squlite database on real Android device

Tags: database, sqlite

I have developed an application that stores some data in an SQLite database.
Now I have installed that application on my real device (not emulator) and it's working fine.
Nou how to find the database in the file manager?

Answer (score 0):

In short unless the device is rooted you cannot as an App's data is protected.

See [Security Tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips)

However, your issue could be solved by referring to [Overview of Shared Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared)

Comment: No . I said in the real device not in the emulator.